# What should the dimension of the mean and variances vectors in the VAE decoder be?

Tags: normal-distribution, autoencoders, variational-bayes

According to "Autoencoding Variational Bayes" article by Kingma and Welling the decoder part of the VAE should roughly look like this:

```
log q(z|x) = log N(z; µ; σ^2I)
where µ = W4h + b4
log σ^2 = W5h + b5
h = tanh(W3x + b3)
```

From this description, I don't understand what the dimension of the mean and variance vector should be? Initially, I thought that it should correspond to the dimension of the input but then people told me that it's not the way the VAE decoder works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimension of the latent representation is a hyperparameter, so it's chosen by the researcher. Typically, the latent space has dimension much smaller than the dimension of the input because a typical goal of VAEs is to create a low-dimensional representation of the input.

Comment: Thank you! So we can assume that latent variable distribution can have any dimensionality. Initially, I thought that it should be somehow connected to the dimensionality of X input. I thought that each pixel of the image input is represented by its own mean and variance that result in the Z distribution with the dimensionality equal to the image dimension. But this was just my confusion about how VAE works.